# How to run Terraform code by using an azure function

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-functions

I need to automatically deploy one or multiple Azure container group when needed. My plan was to use an Azure Function that would run Terraform code specifying the desired resources to be deployed, the problem is that I can't find any documentation on how to run Terraform code by using an Azure Function, is there a better way to do this?

Comment: This sounds like you need some kind of an autoscaling mechanism?

Comment: @MarkoE My need it's more like an on demand deployment that could use azure functions to specify the characteristics of each container group needed and request it with a simple web request

Comment: Are you asking how to use a serverless function as an interface for the Terraform CLI?

Comment: Correct, I need that serverless function to use Terraform CLI so I can provision resources with a Terraform script.

Comment: I realized this is not the correct approach for my project, this isn't the correct usage of terraform, I opted to use Kubernetes to deploy the containers. 
I'm going to delete the question, thanks for your help.

Comment: Instead of deleting, @Gable please mention why it is not the correct approach in the form of an answer and then mention what you opted to do your operations.

Comment: I am also wondering if its possible to execute a terraform binary in Azure Functions.